# Application error uploading file to AWS using carrierwave and fog - heroku deployed app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, fog

I've set heroku config vars with AWS credentials using:

```
heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY=<....>
heroku config:set S3_SECRET_KEY=<....>
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=<....>
```

and verified them on heroku:

```
heroku run rails console

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  puts config.fog_directory
  puts config.fog_credentials
end
```

On my config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb file, I've got:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider              => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
  }
  config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

On app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb file I've got:

```
  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end
```

When deploying the app on heroku everything seems to be ok but trying upload a file leads to an Application Error page... Does this have to do with AWS rather than my code?

Comment: Another related question! Are there any difference between AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and S3_ACCESS_KEY? Also between AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and S3_SECRET_KEY?

Comment: (1) You can set different permission with different access key. (2) S3 access and update permission is set in different place if compare with ec2 connection or other permission, you need customise. (3) show us the error detail.

Comment: Could you post the error output from `heroku logs` when you try this please?

Comment: Here is the error from the logs...

Comment: 2015-01-03T08:41:44.020980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/posts" host=XXX.herokuapp.com request_id=16ea7c1e-84ef-4592-aee1-11c870a29984 fwd="197.36.157.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18510ms status=503 bytes=0

Comment: Did you run 'heroku run rake db:migrate' ?

Comment: @RailsOuter, yes sure...

Comment: Case resolved! H13 error code on heroku has to do with Unicorn timeout set to less than 30s ---- This is the url... https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response